# How to remove particular annotation in mapbox Maps SDK for android?

Tags: android, mapbox-android

private fun removeMarkerFromMap(point: Point){

```
    val pointAnnotationOptions: PointAnnotationOptions =
        PointAnnotationOptions().withPoint(point)

    var annotationID : Long? = null
    pointAnnotationManager.annotations.forEach {
        if(it.point==point)  annotationID=it.id
    }
```

//Remember this point annotation manager should be global & initialised only once
pointAnnotationManager.delete(pointAnnotationOptions.build(annotationID!!, pointAnnotationManager))
}

To delete all annotations
use pointAnnotationManager.deleteAll()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```kotlin
private fun removeMarkerFromMap(point: Point){

    val pointAnnotationOptions: PointAnnotationOptions =
        PointAnnotationOptions().withPoint(point)

    var annotationID : Long? = null
    pointAnnotationManager.annotations.forEach {
        if(it.point==point)  annotationID=it.id
    }
//Remember this point annotation manager should be global & initialised only' once 
pointAnnotationManager
    .delete(pointAnnotationOptions
    .build(
          annotationID!!,
          pointAnnotationManager
     )
)}
```